# What is the value of putchar(c) here '_'?

Tags: c, printf, putchar, kr-c

What is the value of putchar(c) outside loop?

```
main()
{
  int c;

  while (c = getchar() != EOF) {
    printf("printf c_inloop :%d\n",c);
    printf("Putchar c_inside: ");
    putchar(c);
    printf("\n\n");
  }

  putchar(c);
  printf("printf c_outloop %d",c); /*outside loop*/

}
```

When I run the program, say "th"(wtq) and press enter in cmd(Windows):

```
th
printf c_inloop :1
Putchar c_inside:(gives me a smileyface emoticon)

printf c_inloop :1
Putchar c_inside:(gives me a smileyface emoticon)

printf c_inloop :1
Putchar c_inside:(gives me a smileyface emoticon)


^Z (Ctrl + Z)
 printf c_outloop 0
```

Note the space before `printf c_outloop 0`. Is the value of `putchar(c)` Space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you exit the loop, the value of `c` is `EOF`, which isn't a valid character value (that's why it's used to indicate end of file). It makes no sense to pass it to `putchar`.

Comment: so why is that space there? What does it symbolise?

Comment: Nothing. It's just a garbage result from a nonsense operation.

Comment: The value is boolean isn't it? True or false? because if I remove the bracket, the value of printf_c outside becomes -1, isn't that th value of EOF

Comment: What value is boolean? If you mean `c`, it's an integer. Most likely, `EOF` is `-1` on your platform.

Comment: The value of c is boolean is what i meant

Comment: Why is the value when you exit the loop 0, why not -1 as of EOF

Comment: The value is EOF when you exit the loop, which is probably `-1` on your platform. It can't be zero -- zero is a valid character value, so couldn't be used to indicate EOF. Whatever value your platform uses to indicate EOF, it can't be a valid character value.